# Angular Filtering: Problem when Clearing Search Box

Tags: arrays, angular, filter

I Have a list of objects that i'm displaying, and i added a search box to filter a column, now when i enter a value, it works fine and the data is filtered.
The problem is, when i clear the search box, i don't get all the data back, i stay stuck with what i searched first, so i have to refresh every time i want to change the entered value or get the whole list.

Here's my Ts Code :

```
export class AdherentsComponent implements OnInit {
  adherents: adherent[];
  name: string;

  constructor(private adherentService: AdherentService, private alertify: AlertifyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAdherents();
    this.name = "";
  }

  getAdherents() {
    this.adherentService.getAdherents().subscribe((
      adherents: adherent[]) => {
      this.adherents = adherents;
    }, error => { this.alertify.error(error); })
  }

  

  Search() {
    if (this.name.length > 0) {
      this.adherents = this.adherents.filter(res => {
        return res.nomcomplet.toLowerCase().match(this.name.toLowerCase());
      })
    }
    else if (this.name.length === 0) {
      this.adherents = this.adherents;
      console.log(this.adherents.length);
    }
  }



}
```

Here's my Html Code :

```
<body >
<main role="main" class="container" >
<div  class="jumbotron" style="background-color: white;">
  <h2>Liste des Adhérents</h2>
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (input)="Search()" />  
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-light">
<tr>
   <th>Nom Complet</th>
   <th>Grade</th>
   <th>Poste</th>
   <th>Telephone</th>
   <th>E-mail</th>
   <th></th>
 </tr>
 </thead>

     <tr *ngFor="let item of adherents">
       <td>{{item.nomcomplet}}</td>
       <td>{{item.grade}}</td>
       <td>{{item.poste}}</td>
       <td>{{item.telephone}}</td>
       <td>{{item.email}}</td>
       <td><button [routerLink]="['/adherents/', item.id]" style="margin-right: 0.2em;" title="Details" class="btn-sm btn-secondary text-white"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>
        <button [routerLink]="['/adherentEdit/', item.id]"
        style="margin-right: 0.2em;" title="Modifier" class="btn-sm btn-primary text-white"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button></td>
     </tr>
   </table>

   
</div>
</main>
</body>
```

Please how can i modify The Search() Function  so i can dynamically get data from the Array when changing the value in the search box input ?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable for all the values and another one for the values that are displayed to the user. When you search you filter all elements and save them into the array that you are using to display to the user. Same occurs when you clear searchbox, simply get all values and save them to this array.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the value in the property `_adherents` that contains all the values with a new value.

Instead you could

- make `_adherents` private.
- Create another property `current_adherents` that represents an array of your filtered/sorted output.
- Use `current_adherents` in your template.

**example code**

```
export class AdherentsComponent implements OnInit {
  private _adherents: adherent[];
  public current_adherents: adherent[];
  name: string;
  // removed code irrelevant to the question   
  Search() {
    this.current_adherents = this._adherents.filter(res => {
      return res.nomcomplet.toLowerCase().match(this.name.toLowerCase());
    })
  }  
}
```

*Edit: if name is an empty string by definition it will match all elements. So you could remove your if/else logic too ;).*